# Linear Algebra for machine learning

Tags: linear-algebra

Need to find the magnitude for the following two vectors below

The magnitude of the projection of this vector    (5, -2, 3, 6) onto this vector, (1, 2, 7, 3,) is:

Answer (score 0):

The magnitude of a projection is found by the dot product.

```
a = (5,-2,3,6)
b = (1,2,7,3)
```

Make the second vector have unit magnitude with

```
b = b/sqrt(b.b)
```

where `b.b` is `b` dot-product with `b`

And the projection magnitude is then:

```
p = a.b
```

or altogether

```
p = a.b/sqrt(b.b)
```